# how can get the FPDF library

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdf, fpdf

i have found some pdf file geneartion program in php. When i run it i get the following error Warning:

```
Warning: include(helveticab.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\wamp\www\raj19\fpdf.php on line 789

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'helveticab.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in E:\wamp\www\raj19\fpdf.php on line 789
FPDF error : Could not include font metric file
```

I think the fpdf.php is missing .I have searched on their site but i could not find the english version. can anyone provide me full link of english version?

Comment: Your error says `Failed opening 'helveticab.php' ` *that* one is probably missing

Comment: You are mis-interpreting the error message; fpdf.php exists. The file that is missing is helveticab.php

Comment: @srisa @pekka ya you are saying correct but problem is in that .php file there is no response at all if i click .pdf file only it goes what can i do for .php on browser

Comment: you can get it from any print invoice wp free plugin in worst case , most of them are using fpdf

Answer (score 2):

`helveticab.php` is a font definition file, which is shipped with FPDF. Get it here:
http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: ya i got it from that link only but i want when i run in localhost it must go on with .php not .pdf. any ideas u have

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: There is a `font` directory. Copy it into the directory where `fpdf.php` is located, and it runs fine

Answer (score 1):

Since your code is not able to locate font library, add this line to your code.

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','fpdf/font/');
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to copy the entire folder, and check for "fonts" one. Go inside and search for the file you're looking for.

If nothing works. Try with `$font = 'fonts/arial.ttf';`  and in the "fonts" folder put the TTF file. If you don't know where to get it. Search in your explorer "fonts" and get the TTF file by dragging it to the fonts folder or copying it.

If doens't works, copy the code line where you're trying to call the font file.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where the library is in the root directory. if Is in the same place just use 
$str = 'fpdf.php';
require($str);
if your output is in a directory called fpdf and your php output is in another directory i.e. mydoc, you need to go up one step
$str = '../fpdf.php';
if your php output is down 2 steps i.e. root/myfolder/mydoc/output.php then you need to up two steps $str = '../../fpdf/fpdf.php'; i'm assuming that you have your fpdf library in the folder root/fpdf/fpdf.php