# Using FPDF error with font helveticab.php

Tags: php, fpdf

Im attempting to use FPDF, on Windows and using the XAMPP server.

I keep running into this error:

Warning: include(helveticab.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\fpdf.php on line 541

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'helveticab.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\fpdf.php on line 541
FPDF error: Could not include font metric file

Anyone have an idea of how this can be resolved?

Also, I have checked and helveticab.php is installed which is the answer given in similar questions that i looked at.

Thanks

Comment: Repeated Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658136/how-can-get-the-fpdf-library

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why they did it, but if the font is "Arial" they change the font to Helvetica. One of the styles is "c". They append the style to the font, so it searches and adds the fonts and styles. Example is helvetica bold is helveticab, or helvetica italic bold is helveticabi, but helveticac does not exist. To circumvent this, I added the following lines in fpdf.php at around line 498. If the style is "c", we set the style to "":
Code the already have

```
// Test if one of the core fonts
    if($family=='arial')
        $family = 'helvetica';
```

Code I added:

```
if(stripos($style, "c")!==false)
    $style='';
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem but what solves it was I uploaded a folder in the program folder with name font. inside the font folder, I added the following files:
helveticab.php, helvetica.php, helveticabi.php, helvetica-extracompressed.ttf, and helveticai.php
Font folder can be downloaded from https://github.com/Setasign/FPDF.
Just download all the files in https://github.com/Setasign/FPDF/tree/master/font and add them to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another font instead of Arial as like : Helvetica

Hope this will solve the problem :)

Comment: Details on why fpdf doesn't support Arial would be nice.